# How to not calculate in Excel when field is 0

Tags: excel

*Context:*
I am creating an Excel spreadsheet for my friends business. It stores sales data and calculates the persons sales, how much of that was in cash and card and how much commision he gets (percent of amount he sold).

The amount they get is % of the amount they sold plus a set amount in Some cases.

Later i take this amount and process it in a weekly and montlhy overview.

The formula i use for their comission a day is basic :
Cell A - Total sold
Cell B - Agreed comission in %
Cell C - Bonus set amount

Formula is (Cell A * Cell B) + Cell C

**The question**
How Can I set this field to not calculate the formula if Cell A(Total Sold) is empty?

I tried Some formulas i found on the internet but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?  It seems a simple `IF` function would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a brilliant solution, because AFAIK there's no way to generate a blank cell in Excel when you want to leave the value empty, so the best you can do is an empty string. But this should work:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(CellA),"",(CellA*CellB)+CellC)
```

or if you want to ignore zeros too:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(CellA),CellA=0),"",(CellA*CellB)+CellC)
```